# Is there a way to test Quick Actions using XCUITest?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and see that the quick actions are available in the simulator.  Is there a way to test these using XCUITest?  How can we launch the application and select one of these quick actions?

[image]

Comment: XCUITest tests your app, not the springboard.

Comment: Apps often use the springboard so it's perfectly valid to use it for your automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle ID for the springboard is com.apple.springboard. You can interact with it as you would any other application.

`let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")`

and then go from there. To discover its capabilities, enter a debug session and have at it.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work using the springboard and doing springboard.icons["myapp"].press(forDuration: 2) then springboards.buttons["button1"].tap()